# Как реализовать вывод блока div на конкретной странице

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

многоязычный сайт где три главные страницы и на каждой нужно вывести сообщение на её языке. Как это можно реализовать?

Русский язык



    English



    Казак тили

Comment: Что у вас уже есть для локализации?

Comment: делаю сайт на wordpress для локализации использую плагин polylang

Comment: @EugenEray, не совсем дубликат. Там речь идёт про формирование локализованного текста на стороне сервера, а тут имеется ответ с бесскриптовой локализацией на стороне клиента.

Answer (score 1):

Как например:

```css
[lang="ru"] {
  position: relative;
}

.msg {
  display: none;
}

[lang="ru"] .ru {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10%;
}

[lang="en"] .en {
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="msg ru">РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК</span>
<span class="msg en">English</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Сменили на англ.:

```css
[lang="ru"] {
  position: relative;
}

.msg {
  display: none;
}

[lang="ru"] .ru {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10%;
}

[lang="en"] .en {
  color: blue;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="msg ru">РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК</span>
<span class="msg en">English</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Либо, задавать класс `body` - `page-ru`, `page-en`

Если на js, то тот же принцип.

```
if(lang === "ru") { ... } else if(lang === "en") { ... }
```